# What happens after getting all achievements?

Tags: achievements, jetpack-joyride

I've finally finished every achievement in the game,  and yet nothing happens. Is this a glitch or was doing this completely pointless?

Comment: Achievements or trophies in general encourage you to explore a game to its fullest. Some games might reward you for completing certain achievements, but this is far from being the de facto standard.

Answer (score 7):

Nothing gets unlocked or activated when you achieve all the achievements.

They are there to show your progress and offer additional challenges.

Answer (score 1):

Much like "prestiging" in the *Call of Duty* multiplayer, you can choose to restart the game, which will award you with an achievement (A man, my son) and the opportunity to play through the missions again (you keep purchased items).

Answer (score 0):

It's not a glitch. You can just show off your success to your friends. In my point of view, it is just for fun and gives you some challenges, skill and a lot of goals that you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing happens there is no glitch yes you can nag your friends about it and you can start the game again but you keep your gadgets and jetpacks
hope this answers your question!

Comment: Welcome to the ArQAde. Please don't format like that, and what exactly does your "answer" contribute in addition to the ones already here?